# What happens if the callback method takes more than the specified Timer's time period?

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I have the below code. What happens if the Upload method takes more than one minute for completion? Does the timer kick off another call to the Upload method immediately after one minute is over or Does it wait until the method finishes executing? I am implementing this as a windows service.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)    
  Dim tmr As Timer = New Timer(New TimerCallback(AddressOf Upload), Nothing, 1000, **60000**)

  While Not tmr Is Nothing
  End While
End Sub

Public Sub Upload(ByVal o As Object)
  Dim sr As StreamReader
  ..........
  ..........
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though some of your code is confusing (what's with the `While` loop?), I can say yes, the `Timer` will kick off another `Thread` from the `ThreadPool`.

You can use `Monitor`, `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, or `lock` to control re-entrancy. You'll need an object to lock onto and other things tie into your requirements (i.e. the integer specified tells `Monitor` to try for X milliseconds, where 0 means we want the lock immediately):

VB.NET:

```
Private ReadOnly LockerObject As Object = New Object()

If (Monitor.TryEnter(LockerObject, 0)) Then
    Try
        'do your processing
    Catch

    Finally
        'always release the lock
        Monitor.Exit(LockerObject)
    End Try
End If
```

C#:

```
private readonly object LockerObject = new object();

if (Monitor.TryEnter(LockerObject, 0))
{
    try
    {
        //do your processing
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        //always release the lock
        Monitor.Exit(LockerObject);
    }
}
else
{
    //do something else here if needs be.
}
```

EDIT: Oops, this is VB.NET! Let me convert my code...

Comment: I used while loop to keep my timer running forever. With out the while loop my program is ending. 
I will try this locking mechanism and let you know.
Thank you for the solution..

Comment: Ah, I see, well, you won't need that when it's running as a Windows Service, but for simulation I'd recommend using `Console.Write("Press any key to stop simulation"); Console.ReadKey();`.

Comment: That's in a console application only, which is using the service class you create, obviously!